# Can't connect Network Interface to VM in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, hyper-v, azure-virtual-network

I created a VM in HyperV and modified it to be a DLP machine.
I saved the machine's disk and uploaded it to Azure on a new VM and when I tried to connect a Network Interface to the VM it didn't work, I could do that and it seemed as if it worked but when went to *Networking* it said:

```
This network interface does not contain network security groups
```

Which basically means it didn't set anything, also when tried to add a new NIC (Network Interface) for the third time the following error was given:

```
Failed to attach network interface 'Dlp-machine-NetworkINT' to virtual machine 'Dlp-machine'. Error: The number of network interfaces for virtual machine Dlp-machine exceeds the maximum allowed for the virtual machine size Standard_D2s_v3. The number of network interfaces is 3 and the maximum allowed is 2.
```

So it seems like the former NICs were saved but were not really applied or used.

I came to realize that what's the problem is that since the VM is using a local disk it's configured to use the local NIC.
Anyone has encountered something like this when uploading a local disk to Azure and knows what to do?

Answer (score 0):

What the second error says is that your VM is limited to only 2 NICs by its SKU. You should use `Standard_D8s_v3` (or some other SKU) to allow to use 4 NICs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes-general#dsv3-series-1

Comment: I don't think it's the point.. It stops me from adding a NIC due to too many NICs already used when none are actually set in there and I think limiting NICs to 4 instead of 2 won't change the fact it doesn't actually sets any of the NICs to the VM.

Comment: its the platform level limitation, not the OS level. platform doesnt care how many NICs are inside the OS. so you are not correct. there are in fact 2 interfaces bound to the VM already if you are getting this error